# Problem regarding cantour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

which of the  following statement is True ?

[image]

My attempt : i thinks  option 4 is  true  by  using cauchy reimann equation

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: 1) is false. 2) and 3) are true.

Comment: Can you show how you got 4) using C-R equations?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir any  hints  /solution  ??

Comment: @Kavi sir i take $p(z)=z$ and $q(z)=1$ then we would have $p(z)\overline{q(z)}=\bar{z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4) is not true. This follows from 2) with $p(z)=q(z)=z$.

Proof of 2) : just note that the complex conjugate of  $z^{n}$ is $\frac 1 {z^{n}}$ on $\gamma$.

3) follows by Cauchy's Theorem.

1) is false: take $n=m+1$. The integral becomes $2\pi i$.

Comment: thanks  u kavi sir